# Webserver does not overwrite file

Tags: jquery, file, webserver

I'm working on a site and i'm trying to upload a jQuery file with FilzZilla:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function getParameter(paramName) {
    var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
        i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

    for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
        val = params[i].split("=");
        if (val[0] == paramName) {
            return unescape(val[1]);
        }

        if (searchString == '') {
        } else if (searchString == 'page=contact') {
            $('#contactknop').css("color", "#00aeef");
    $("#contactknop").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
    $("#contactknop").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
        } else if (searchString == 'page=visie-missie-en-doel') {
            $('#visie').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=mederwerkers') {
            $('#medewerkers').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=diciplines') {
            $('#disciplines').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=slimmezorg') {
            $('#slimmezorg').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=collectief') {
            $('#collectief').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=lesrooster') {
            $('#lesrooster').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=lidvanleef') {
            $('#lidvanleef').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=algemenevoorwaarden') {
            $('#algemenevoorwaarden').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=prijslijst') {
            $('#prijslijst').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=vakorganisaties') {
            $('#vakorganisatie').css("color", "#00aeef");
        } else if (searchString == 'page=partners') {
            $('#partners').css("color", "#00aeef");
        }
    }
    return null;
}



$("#visie").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#visie").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#medewerkers").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#medewerkers").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#disciplines").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#disciplines").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#slimmezorg").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#slimmezorg").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#collectief").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#collectief").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#lesrooster").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#lesrooster").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#lidvanleef").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#lidvanleef").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#algemenevoorwaarden").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#algemenevoorwaarden").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#prijslijst").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#prijslijst").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#vakorganisatie").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#vakorganisatie").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#partners").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#partners").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

$("#contactknop").mouseover(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#00aeef"})});
$("#contactknop").mouseout(function(){$(this).css({"color":"#000000"})});

getParameter();

});
```

but my site just outputs the old file. I had this problem a few days ago to and i solved it by renaming the file and link everything back together.

you can see the website file here:
[site](http://www.preview04.nl/js/default.js)

Comment: Does pressing Ctrl+F5 a few times make it all better?

Comment: no but i'm working on a mac so i think that control f5 not works

Comment: On Mac it's a differen't key, i forget which. But, closing your browser completely (including separate windows) and re-opening it should have the same effect. What you are describing sounds like the normal caching that a browser does. This caching can be forced to be cleared by either including proper caching headers, or by adding a version number to the script such as `src="myscript.js?v=1.0.0"`

Comment: that is what i thought to but i have closed all browsers restart the computer and looking it on a different browser but it still does not update the file

Comment: Well, I use filezilla too and i'm not having this issue. When i upload a new file over the old one, it asks me if i want to overwrite, i choose yes, and it overwrites the file. You may be having a problem with the setup of the ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your JavaScript file is being cached.

You can try to prevent the browser from caching your file(s). This should help:
[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)